# SQL Server MAX of Multiple Names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query to get all the MAX counts of a room that have a reservation, my query returns everything correctly but when I try to find MAX it will only return 1 result instead of 3 that should be showing up it will only return the max count.

Current Results: Shows only the MAX of 1 hotel

```
HotelName                      RoomType             Room Count
------------------------------ -------------------- -----------
MGM Grand                      Single               6
```

Results of the query before the HAVING COUNT:

```
HotelName                      RoomType             Room Count
------------------------------ -------------------- -----------
The Mirage                     Double               3
The Palazzo                    Double               1
MGM Grand                      Double Deluxe        4
MGM Grand                      Family               2
The Mirage                     Family               4
MGM Grand                      Single               6
The Palazzo                    Suite                1
```

Expected Results: Note: on The Palazzo since is has two that are the same count having it show both or one or another would work

```
HotelName                      RoomType             Room Count
------------------------------ -------------------- -----------
MGM Grand                      Single               6
The Mirage                     Family               4
The Palazzo                    Suite                1
```

Current Script:

```
SELECT h.HotelName, hr.RoomType, COUNT(*) AS 'Room Count'
FROM RESERVATIONDETAIL AS rd
JOIN ROOM r ON r.RoomID = rd.RoomID
JOIN HOTELROOMTYPE hr ON hr.HotelRoomTypeID = r.HotelRoomTypeID 
JOIN HOTEL h ON h.HotelID = hr.HotelID
WHERE rd.CheckinDate >= '140901' AND rd.CheckinDate <= '141031'
GROUP BY h.HotelName, hr.RoomType
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(SELECT MAX(RoomCount)
FROM 
(SELECT h.HotelName, COUNT(*) AS RoomCount
FROM RESERVATIONDETAIL AS rd
JOIN ROOM r ON r.RoomID = rd.RoomID
JOIN HOTELROOMTYPE hr ON hr.HotelRoomTypeID = r.HotelRoomTypeID 
JOIN HOTEL h ON h.HotelID = hr.HotelID
WHERE rd.CheckinDate >= '140901' AND rd.CheckinDate <= '141031'
GROUP BY h.HotelName, hr.RoomType)x)
```

Comment: You need `MAX(COUNT)...GROUPBY HotelName`  If you MAX(Count) on just the records you'll get the MAX of all the records.  By using group by you aggregate on all the various hotel names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [row_number function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) should get you what you want.  There might be a way to do this with one less subquery, but I believe the general idea would be:

```sql
select d.HotelName, d.RoomType, d.[Room Count]
from (
  select d.*, row_number() over (partition by HotelName order by [Room Count] desc) rn
  from (
    SELECT h.HotelName, hr.RoomType, COUNT(*) AS 'Room Count'
    FROM RESERVATIONDETAIL AS rd
    JOIN ROOM r ON r.RoomID = rd.RoomID
    JOIN HOTELROOMTYPE hr ON hr.HotelRoomTypeID = r.HotelRoomTypeID 
    JOIN HOTEL h ON h.HotelID = hr.HotelID
    WHERE rd.CheckinDate >= '140901' AND rd.CheckinDate <= '141031'
    GROUP BY h.HotelName, hr.RoomType
  ) d
) d
where d.rn = 1
```